# Find the kth lowest sum of unique pair in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array of numbers, each number represents the difficulty of a problem. People standing in a line should choose any two problems to solve. The two chosen problems should be different and the pair of problems should not be picked by anyone previously. Since they know the difficulties they'll choose the pair whose sum of difficulties is minimum.

Find the minimum sum of difficulties for the person whose standing in kth position in the line. i.e kth minimum sum of unique pair from an array.

Approach 1: Brute force approach(O(n<sup>2</sup>)) to calculate all possible unique sum and store that in an array and sorted the unique sum array to get the kth element.

Approach 2: Sort the difficulties array and choose the minimal elements(for first 4 elements we can have 6 unique pairs. so if k is less than or equal to 6 we can use first 4 elements in the sorted array to find the minimum sum) and did the approach 1 with the minimal array.

These 2 approaches did not solve the timeout cases. Need a solution with improved time efficiency.

Note: Different problem can have same difficulty level(i.e. array can contain duplicate numbers) also and not in sorted order by default.

```
difficulties = [1,4,3,2,4]

Person comes first chooses: 1+2 = 3
2nd person: 1+3 = 4
3rd person: 1+4 (or) 1+4(since difficulty of two problems are 4) (or) 2+3 = 5
4th person: 2+3 (or) 1+4(based on the previous selection) = 5
```

Final answer needed is only the minimum sum not the actual elements.

Assume the constraints to be: 
2 <= N <= 10<sup>5</sup> 
1 <= k <= N*(N-1)/2 
1 <= difficulties[i] <= 10<sup>9</sup>

where, 
N is the length of the array 
k is the position in which the person has to choose the problems

Comment: Just to be clear. If we have an array of 5 elements, say `A B C D E`, then the pairs to choose from are `A+B, A+C, A+D, A+E, B+C, B+D, B+E, C+D, C+E, and D+E`. So we could have up to 10 people in the line. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Total no of unique pairs. i.e. n(n-1)/2 pairs

Comment: Updated the question with tried approaches and an example.

Comment: Could you give me some problem link so that I can try submitting before answering here? Also, for the input array in your example `difficulties = [1,4,3,2,4]` and the statement "The two problems should be different", means that I cannot make two pair of `(1+4)` and `(1+4)`? You count them as different using their actual elements or their indices?

Comment: @risingStark this question was from a private contest. Not able to find any similar problem. For the question, two problems should be different but different problems can have same difficulty level.

Comment: In the above array, 4 was repeated. So, will two pairs of (1, 4) be counted as different or not. Because if you go by index, then they are different but `difficulties[i]` is same.

Comment: This can be solved in O(NlogN + KlogK) time. Which is good as long as `K <= N`. It's not so good if `K > N`. The worst case for K is O(N^2). O(NlogN + KlogK) becomes O(N^2 logN) when K is O(N^2). Are there any constraints on `K`?

Comment: @risingStark it will be considered different.. we can have (1+4), (1+4), (2+3) for a sum of difficulty level 5

Comment: @user3386109 K can be and most probably will be greater than N

Comment: Updated the question with some more details.

Comment: I have added the answer below. It was a nice problem to solve. I hope this much detailed explanation helps and if it does, please upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `k <= n*(n-1)/2`. If not, then no answer possible.
We can use binary search to solve the problem. We binary search on the possible sum of pairs.
Here,
 low = minimum sum possible i.e. `low = difficulties[0] + difficulties[1]`, and
 high = maximum sum possible i.e. `high = difficulties[n-1] + difficulties[n-2]`.

So, `mid = low + (high - low)/2`
Now, in 1 iteration of binary search we would count the pairs of indices `(i, j), i < j` such that `difficulties[i] + difficulties[j] <= mid`. If the count is less than k, `low = mid + 1` else if count >= k, `high = mid`. Now, this one iteration can be done in `O(NlogN)`.

You can do this till `(high - low) > 1`. So, each time you reduce your search space by half. So, total time complexity would be `O(N*logN*logMaxsum)` which for `N <= 1e6` and `difficulties[i] <= 1e18` would run in less than 1s.

Now high can be equal to low or high can be equal to low +1. The answer can be equal to `low` or `high`. Now, you just need to solve the problem whether low is a possible sum(can be solved easily in `O(N)` using Hashing) and no. of pairs of indices `(i, j), i < j` such that `difficulties[i] + difficulties[j] <= low`. If both conditions satify then this is your answer. If not then high is the answer.
**Running an example testcase:**
Lets' consider the initial array, `difficulties = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4]` and `k = 6`.
You first sort the array costing us `O(NlogN)`. After sorting `difficulties = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`
All the pairs `n*(n-1)/2 = 10` would be:

1. `(1 + 2) => 3`
2. `(1 + 3) => 4`
3. `(1 + 4) => 5`
4. `(1 + 4) => 5`
5. `(2 + 3) => 5`
6. `(2 + 4) => 6`
7. `(2 + 4) => 6`
8. `(3 + 4) => 7`
9. `(3 + 4) => 7`
10. `(4 + 4) => 8`

This is more of a pseudocode to understand the running of the logic.

```
sort(difficulties)
low = difficulties[0] + difficulties[1] // Minimum possible sum
high = difficulties[n-1] + difficulties[n-2] // Maximum possible sum

while(high - low > 1){
    mid = low + (high - low)/2
    count = all pairs (i, j) and i < j such that difficulties[i] + difficulties[j] <= mid.
    if(count < k){
        low = mid +1 
    }else{
        high = mid
    }
}
```

```
Iteration 1:
low = 3
high = 8
mid = 5
count = 5 [(1 + 2), (1 + 3), (1 + 4), (1 + 4), (2 + 3)]
count < k, so low = mid + 1 = 6

----------

Iteration 2:
low = 6
high = 8
mid = 7
count = 9 [(1 + 2), (1 + 3), (1 + 4), (1 + 4), (2 + 3), (2 + 4), (2 + 4), (3 + 4), (3 + 4)]
count >= k, so high= mid = 7
```

Now, while loop stops since high(7) - low(6) = 1.
Now, you need to check if sum 6 is possible and count of all (i, j) >= k. if it is then low is the answer and in this case it is true. So, answer = 6 for k = 6.

To implement the count thing, you can again do a binary search. Choose first index as `i` then you just need to find the upper bound of `mid - difficulties[i]` in the array `[i+1, n-1]`. Then increment i by 1 and repeat the same. So, you go over every index `0 <= i <= n-1` and find its upper bound in the array search space of `[i+1, n-1]` and this each iteration takes `O(NlogN)`.

---

To see why is the last step of checking if low or high is a possible sum or not, try running the algorithm for the array `difficulties = [10, 40, 30, 20, 40]`.

**UPDATE:**
Below is the complete working code with the time complexity of `O(N*logN*logMaxsum)` including comments for clear understanding of the logic.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int

using namespace std;

void solve();
int main(){
    solve();
    return 0;
}

map<int, int> m;
vector<ll> difficulties;
ll countFunction(ll sum){
    /*
    Function to count all the pairs of indices (i, j) such that
    i < j and  (difficulties[i] + difficulties[j]) <= sum
    */
    ll count = 0;

    int n = (int)difficulties.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        /*
        Here the outer for loop means that if I choose difficulties[i]
        as the first element of the pair, then the remaining sum is
        m - difficulties[i], so we just need to find the upper_bound of this value
        to find the count of all pairs with sum <= m.
        upper_bound is an in-built function in C++ STL.
        */
        int x= upper_bound(difficulties.begin(), difficulties.end(), sum-difficulties[i]) - (difficulties.begin() + i + 1);
        if(x<=0){
            /*
            We break here because the condition of i < j is violated
            and it will be violated for remaining values of i as well.
            */
            break;
        }
        //cout<<"x = "<<x<<endl;
        count += x;
    }
    return count;
}


bool isPossible(ll sum){
    /*
    Hashing based solution to check if atleast 1 pair with
    a particular exists in the difficultiesay.
    */
    int n = (int) difficulties.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        /*
        Choosing the ith element as first element of pair
        and checking if there exists an element with value = sum - difficulties[i]
        */
        if(difficulties[i] == (sum - difficulties[i])){
            // If the elements are equal then the frequency must be > 1
            if(m[difficulties[i]] > 1){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            if(m[sum - difficulties[i]] > 0){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void solve(){
    ll i, j, n, k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    difficulties.resize(n);
    m.clear(); // to run multiple test-cases
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>difficulties[i];
        m[difficulties[i]]++;
    }
    sort(difficulties.begin(), difficulties.end());


    // Using binary search on the possible values of sum.
    ll low = difficulties[0] + difficulties[1]; // Lowest possible sum after sorting
    ll high = difficulties[n-1] + difficulties[n-2]; // Highest possible sum after sorting
    while((high-low)>1){
        ll mid = low + (high - low)/2;
        ll count = countFunction(mid);
        //cout<<"Low = "<<low<<" high = "<<high<<" mid = "<<mid<<" count = "<<count<<endl;
        if (k > count){
            low = mid + 1;
        }else{
            high = mid;
        }
    }

    /*
    Now the answer can be low or high and we need to check
    if low or high is a possible sum and does it satisfy the constraints of k.

    For low to be the answer, we need to count the number of pairs with sum <=low.
    If this count is >=k, then low is the answer.
    But we also need to check whether low is a feasible sum.
    */
    if(isPossible(low) && countFunction(low)>=k){
        cout<<low<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<high<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: this still looks more time consuming since the iteration is based on maxSum. difficulties[i] can be up to 10<sup>9</sup> and maxSum will be sum of two such elements where the length of the array is comparatively small.

Comment: @Manojkumar The binary search will need a maximum of 30 iterations.  Each of which involves a scan over 10^5 elements.  So you maximum need a few million operations.  By contrast `k` can be in the billions.  It may look time consuming, but it isn't.

Comment: @Manojkumar There is a log involved for the maximum sum of elements. Even if difficulties[i] would have been upto 10<sup>18</sup>, then also log(10<sup>18</sup>) is atmost 64.

Comment: @Manojkumar The stated complexity of this solution is `N * logN * logS` where N is the number of elements in the array, and S is the maximum sum of 2 elements.  So given N=1e5 and S=2e9, the number of operations is estimated at `1e5 * 17 * 31 = 53e6`. That's a fairly reasonable number if the goal is to solve the problem in under one second.

Comment: @risingStark if the binary search goes to the last part of array then counting the no of pairs operation can go near to n^2 right? can you explain this part

Comment: @risingStark can you clarify my query i may be wrong

Comment: @Manojkumar I don't understand what you mean by "last part of the array"

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about the last 10-20 elements remaining. Even if the algorithm performs as O(n^2), it is not a big deal. You worry about time complexities when n reaches 10^4 or 10^5.

Comment: @risingStark simple brute force approach I mentioned in the question performs in O(n^2). this answer is more time consuming than that

Comment: You clearly don't understand how this code works. My algorithm is not O(n^2) and I said that in the last 10-20 elements, the binary search might not get you any advantage and thus the algorithm might look like O(n^2) but it is not. It will be accepted on any judge with the above mentioned constraints.

Comment: @risingStark as far as I know the count pairs operations is taking more time. can you post the actual code logic instead of pseudocode

Comment: @Manojkumar You also gotta do put in some effort to solve the problem. I have given enough hints as well pseudocode for you, if you get stuck in between.

Comment: @risingStark the reason I posted this question in stackoverflow is to get some help to solve this problem efficiently. I said as far as I know the count pairs operation can be done in n^2 time. I really appreciate your time and efforts for this answer. But it is not clear to me how this count pair operation can be done efficiently.

Comment: @Manojkumar I have added the complete working code and the `countFunction()` having O(NlogN) time complexity.